# Read Soap XML Request in Java Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, envelope

My Soap xml request looks like :

```
<payload xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <D:Envelope xmlns:D="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <SOAP:Header xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            ....
        </SOAP:Header>
        <D:Body id="Body">
            ....
        </D:Body>
    </D:Envelope>
</payload>
```

When I remove the payload element it works perfect, but with above request, I get an error as "Unable to create envelope from given source because the root element is not named "Envelope"

Question: How can I read the request in Java Spring-boot?

Comment: The error is telling you all you need to know. With the `payload` tag it isn't a soap request. For a SOAP request the `Envelope` tag needs to be the first one.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, but how can we customize the request data (remove the payload tag) so that we are able to read from the Envelope tag. I am using Java Spring as framework. Our Soap request will be in above format only that is with envelope wrapped in payload tag, that is not going to change.

Comment: If it is wrapped it isn't a soap request. Why is it wrapped in payload in the first place?